# Stop-Process doesnt take -id or input from piped value

Tags: windows, powershell

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $input -ScriptBlock {Get-Process -Name amazon-ssm-agent | foreach {Stop-Process -Force} -ErrorAction Stop}

When i pass the value to stop-process, its throwing error "cant bind null value to ID "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop-Process is not actually receiving any object the way it is written which is why you get that error.  When in a ForEach-Object block you need to use $_ in your code block to represent each object being passed in.  Just need to add `$_ |` in front of Stop-Process

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $input -ScriptBlock {Get-Process -Name amazon-ssm-agent | foreach {$_ | Stop-Process -Force} -ErrorAction Stop}
```